# Is there a simple way to filter a dataframe in Python by the contents of multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiple codings on various variables (so like Adress 1 = "foo", Adress 2 = "bar", etc..., the same for other variables).

I would like to write a script that can filter the dataframe in the way of 'any Adress = "foo"' and can take an user input for which variable to filter. Is there a way to do that or do I need to write the script individually for each variable? (For which I already have a solution in my mind, I would just like to have a more elegeant solution)

My Dataframe looks like this.

```
Adress 1    Adress 2 Family Name 1 Family Name 2
0   Austin    New York        Miller         Baker
1    Paris      Austin         Smith          Yang
2  Detroit  Kopenhagen         Baker         Smith
```

I would like to give the user the ability to ask for a filter like Adress = Austin, and the output to look like:

```
  Adress 1    Adress 2 Family Name 1 Family Name 2
0   Austin    New York        Miller         Baker
1    Paris      Austin         Smith          Yang
```

Comment: Please explain this with the help of sample input and expected output.

Comment: An expression like this `df[(df['A']==1) & (df['B']==2)]` would do the job.

Comment: @RuthgerRighart Yes, this would work, but then I'd need to write an individual function for each of my variables, I hoped that there'd be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a DataFrame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Address1':['Austin','Paris', 'Houston'], 'Address2':['New York', 'Austin', 'SF'], 'FamilyName1':['Miller', 'Smith', 'John'], 'FamilyName2':['Baker', 'Yang', 'Peter']})
```

Check which columns contains the string Address and then verify which of these variables have value 'Austin'.

```
ndf = df.loc[:, list(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(pat = 'Address')])] == 'Austin'
```

Summarize to a list if a row contained a True.

```
list(ndf.any(1))
```

Select rows that contain a True, that is in this case Austin:

```
df[list(ndf.any(1))]
```